# Comparing two XML files with IEnumerable.Except()

Tags: c#, xml, compare, ienumerable, linq-to-xml

With the following code:

```
    XDocument aDoc = XDocument.Load(fileA);
    XDocument bDoc = XDocument.Load(fileB);

    var commonfromA = aDoc.Descendants("Project").Except(bDoc.Descendants("Project"));
```

I compare the following XML:

aDoc.xml

```
<Employees>
      <Project ID="1" Name="Project1"/>
      <Project ID="2" Name="Project2"/>
</Employees>
```

bDoc.xml

```
<Employees>
  <Project ID="1" Name="Project1"/>
  <Project ID="3" Name="Project3"/>
</Employees>
```

When I execute the code I obtain

```
<Project ID="1" Name="Project1"/>
<Project ID="2" Name="Project2"/>
```

Rather than

```
<Project ID="2" Name="Project2"/> **Which is the elements that are in A but not in B**
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's because none of the elements in aDoc *are* actually in bDoc. If you ask each of those elements for its parents, they will report different results.

If you're happy just getting the IDs, it's easy:

```
var idsJustInA = aDoc.Descendants("Project")
                     .Select(x => (int) x.Attribute("ID"))
                     .Except(bDoc.Descendants("Project"))
                                 .Select(x => (int) x.Attribute("ID")));
```

If you want the elements themselves, you could *either* pass an `IEqualityComparer<XElement>` to compare elements by ID, or you could use something like [`ExceptBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var justInA = aDoc.Descendants("Project")
                  .ExceptBy(bDoc.Descendants("Project"),
                            x => (int) x.Attribute("ID"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont understand exactly what do you mean by "none of the elements in aDoc are actually in bDoc"

Comment: @kmxillo: They're different elements, because they're in different documents. Taken *on their own* they're equalivalent, but they're in a different context (they have different parents). I don't even know offhand whether XElement overrides Equals...

Comment: Note that they would *still* be different elements even if they were in the same document (i.e., if a document has "duplicate" nodes, those nodes won't be equal).

Comment: @Brian: True - they would have different siblings, positions etc.